# How to remove "publish metabox" from each post type

Tags: admin, metabox

Is there any way, how to remove "Publish metabox" from each post type (post,page,custom_post_type) anything.

I know how to remove it manually, for each post type, but how to do it globally?

```
remove_metabox(...)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're familiar with Browser Developer Tools you can quickly find the metabox ID ( which is the container div id ). In this case it's called `submitdiv`. We can remove it by using the [`remove_meta_box()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_meta_box) function which has a format like this:

```
remove_meta_box( 'metabox_id', 'post_type', 'default_position' );
remove_meta_box( 'submitdiv',  'post',      'side'             );
```

Here's a [list of default metabox ids](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_meta_box#Parameters). If we want to remove a certain metabox from *all* post types we first need to get all the post types using [`get_post_types()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_types) function which returns an array. Then we can loop through and remove the metabox passing the `post_type` into our `remove_meta_box()` function.

```
/**
 * Hide Metaboxes For All Post Types
 */
function hide_publish_metabox() {
    $post_types = get_post_types( '', 'names' );

    if( ! empty( $post_types ) ) {
        foreach( $post_types as $type ) {
            remove_meta_box( 'submitdiv', $type, 'side' );
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'do_meta_boxes', 'hide_publish_metabox' );
```